# I want to print a pattern of letters and would like if there is something to improvise the code I have written in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Below is the code, I would like if someone could improve this code further:

```
i=0


while i<4:

    if i==0:
        print()
        print(chr(65),end="")
        i=i+1
    if i==1:
        print()
        print(chr(65) ,end="")
        print(chr(66) ,end="")
        i=i+1
    if i==2:
        print()
        print(chr(65), end="")
        print(chr(66), end="")
        print(chr(67), end="")
        i=i+1

    if i==3:
        print()
        print(chr(65), end="")
        print(chr(66), end="")
        print(chr(67), end="")
        print(chr(68), end="")
        i=i+1
```

output:

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
```

Comment: Have you learned about "for loops" already? Try replacing each "i == ..." code block with a for loop (you'd have 4 loops). Then see if you can write those 4 "for loop" as just 1 "for loop", removing the "i==.." lines. Finally, see if you can change your outer "while loop" with an outer "for loop".

Comment: (btw, in case this is homework, it's better practice to mention it in the question, so we only give hints rather than full answer. Welcome and good luck learning programming! It's hard at first but rewarding.)

Comment: @BorisDalstein - it doesn't matter if its homework, mentioning it would just add noise and should be removed so it doesn't detract from the question

Comment: @Sayse Yes it matters, otherwise people just write finished answers as below, and Stelly.Tony loses an opportunity to learn (and post his own answer)

Comment: @BorisDalstein - [Should homework questions disclose that they are homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376394/should-homework-questions-disclose-that-they-are-homework-questions)

Comment: @Sayse The actual entry on the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225) is much more nuanced: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) In particular, it advises to treat "homework questions" differently, not posting full answers, to help the OP learn. Stelly.Tomy: in case you prefer guidance only (for more effective learning), perhaps in future questions you may want to add something like "if possible, I would prefer general guidance rather than full answers, to help me progress". Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use two `for` loops:

```
for w in range(5):
  for c in range(w):
    print(chr(65+c), end="")
  print()
```

The outer loop if for the length of the line and the inner for the characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two for loops. 1st loop for controlling the number of char you want in each line. 2nd loop prints characters.

Try this.

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(65,i+66):
        print(chr(j),end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Yeah, Agreed. @Sayse changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you how you can use a `FOR LOOP` correctly. I'm going to use my own exercise and then YOU find a way to implement it into your code.

**VARIABLES**
As you know, `variables` can be assigned many many different values. Of which, can be made into a `list`.

**LISTS**
So if I wanted to create a grocery list I could write the code as follows:
`grocery_list = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Gummy Bears"]`

So now the `variable` `grocery_list` is equal to 3 separate strings.

**FOR LOOPS**
Now to do something to each item on that `list`, (or any `list` for that matter) we use something called a `for loop`. The `for loop` creates only one temporary `variable` to be used for each item in your `list` in order.

Now listen carefully, this may be clear in a second.

Once the first item (which is assigned to a temporary `variable`) is done, it moves on to the second item by assigning it to the same temporary `variable`, effectively overwriting it.

Here is the syntax of the `for loop` followed by a more plain English translation.

```
for every_item in my_list:
    do_this
```

Translates to this:

```
"For every_item (one at a time, in order)
in my_list (that I've already created):
do the following with those items
which are assigned to the
variable, 'each_item'."
```

So if I wanted to `print` out all of the items in my `grocery_list`, I can reference the plain English and regular syntax examples I've written earlier.

```
for each_item in grocery_list:
    print(each_item)
```

"For every single item, in order, assign that particular item to this `variable`, and then `print` that `variable`."

And again just to emphasize:

"For every single item, (both in order AND only one at a time) assign to the FIRST item in the list to THIS variable I've decided to call: each_item. THEN, repeat for the SECOND item, followed by the third item and so on."

**One more example**
Maybe with those items in my `list`, I want to show that I have already purchased them. In that case I could write:

```
for each_item in grocery_list:
    print(each_item + " purchased)
```

For loops are so ingrained in programming it's not even funny. So please make sure that you read up as much as you can. Hope this helped.